# CSS / JavaScript digit counter

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, counter

basically, what I am looking for is an animation for digits, a great example would be on this site:
http://www.arkanbuilds.com/

If you scroll down you'll see their 'Builds completed' etc counting up.

How do I do this? I have NO knowledge of Javascript neither jQuery if those are necessary, so help would be appreciated.

Also a small sub-question that links to this question; how can I make a number increase monthly / yearly etc, like on that website, the 'months online'.

I would appreciate the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// this interval will repeat itself every 50 milliseconds
var handler = setInterval(function() {
    // get the element that holds the number
    var numberContainer = document.getElementById("number");
    // get the number. it starts with 0
    var number = parseInt(numberContainer.innerText, 10);
    // increase it by 1, or 2 (number += 2;)
    number++;
    // update the number in the element
    numberContainer.innerText = number;
    // set a limit. if the number is greater than/equal to 50
    // stop the interval
    if (number >= 50) {
        clearInterval(handler);
    }
}, 50);
```

```html
<div id="number">0</div>
```

Comment: Hey; can I ask, how can I make multiple counters? I coppied the HTML 3 times and the javascript 3 times but it didn't work, instead only of the html was working and was just increasing 1000+

Comment: @arrey [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kL5k5Ls6/)

Comment: @akinury hey mate, I am coppying the Fiddle but I can't get your latest fiddle to work... But the previous code did :/

Comment: @arrey The code is really simple and self-explanatory. I can't help  without seeing your current code.